# MySQL does not order correctly using UNIX timestamp

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have this php code:

(from my database class)

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM" . CON_TBL. " WHERE a = $b ORDER BY thedate DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
```

The dates (unix timestamp) on the DB are:

```
1138322340
1617584160
1617673680
759952800
```

I got this result:

```
30-Jan-1994 12:00
05-Apr-2021 20:48
04-Apr-2021 19:56
26-Jan-2006 18:39
```

The first date should be the last:

```
05-Apr-2021 20:48
04-Apr-2021 19:56
26-Jan-2006 18:39
30-Jan-1994 12:00
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: *The dates (unix timestamp) on the DB are:* In MySQL the column of TIMESTAMP datatype cannot store these values.

Comment: You would get exactly that result if `thedate` were a text column.  What, EXACTLY, is the datatype for `thedate`?

Comment: And, for what it's worth, what you're showing up there is not PHP code.  It's SQL code.  Nothing here has anything to do with PHP.

Comment: If `thedate` is a string, convert it to a number with `ORDER BY 0+thedate DESC`

Comment: @Akina The "date" column was defined as varchar storing unix ts, that is why it was behaving incorrectly

Comment: @TimRoberts It is PHP, I omitted some code, already edited the original post.

Comment: @Barmar yes, good tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thedate column was a VARCHAR instead of an INT, once I changed the column to INT the ORDER was corrected.